# Get completely loaded webpage sourcecode in java as rendered by browser

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, web-scraping

There are few webpage which employs some javascript/ajax calls to fill some fields in webpage during page load or after page load. One example is http://www.sohos.co.uk/MEN-T-Shirts/Iron-Fist-Mens-Clothing/--Iron-Fist-Bloody-Mess-T--Shirt_ct271bd5pd197.html where content in size drop down box is filled by use of javascript.

Is it possible to get fully loaded page of this type in Java? I think, simply using HttpClient or other methods will not suffice but using Selenium, if this can be done, it would be really  great.

I want some generic solution which could be applied for all websites.

Any input/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Jitendra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium's [WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) supports such emulation through different implementations. One of which is [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) (a headless java browser) - take a look.

Comment: thanks bozho,  One thing I would like to know, would it require site specific coding. I mean I don't want to inspect code of a page and then call appropiate functions. I want it some generic soln.

Comment: But I would definitely give it a try.

Comment: HI bozho. I have tried both webdriver and htmluniot. but both are Return html page content only. '